# mysqldump gives You must use option --tab with --fields-... error when attempting to export to csv

Tags: mysql, export

I am trying to use mysqldump to export a table to csv. The particular command I am using is like this:

```
mysqldump -u my_user -pmy_password --fields-terminated-by=',' --fields-enclosed-by='' ––lines–terminated–by='\n' --fields-optionally-enclosed-by='' ––tab /my/path/ --default-character-set='utf8' --no-create-info --host my_host my_base my table
```

However, it keeps giving me this mysqldump:

> You must use option --tab with --fields-...

error each time I do it. Tried to google all over the place and no one even seems to know about this error existing. Did anyone encounter a similar problem?

Comment: Your command line has `—tab` instead of `--tab`, is that the issue?

Comment: No, it's definitely --tab. I checked.

Comment: When looking closely, your `--tab` doesn't contain `-` and it's some other character looks the same. Try replacing `––` with `--`.